# Powershell error "Invalid Parameter - Files" - what does it mean?

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a script that runs fine on a local machine with Windows 7. When I try to run it on another running Windows Server 2012, I get the error:

```
Invalid Parameter - Files
```

I have ImageMagick installed on the server machine and I have access to all the paths. I don't understand what I should be troubleshooting. Any ideas?

UPDATE: I see that because i have a space before the word "Files" in my source path, this may be causing the issue. However not sure how to force the path.

My script is:

```
# PowerShell script
# Date: 21/04/2016
# Purpose: Used to convert the first page of a TIF to a PDF file

# Basic concept - using ImageMagick
# convert  source.pdf[0]  output.jpeg

#TIFF source folder
$source = "\\Server12\US Files\NV"

# Select first page of TIFs in folder and convert them to PDFs
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -filter *.tif | %{ convert "$($_.FullName -Replace ".tif+$", ".tif[0]")" "C:\US\NV\$($_.Name -Replace ".tif+$", ".pdf")" }
```

Comment: Replace the `convert "$...` part with a `write-host` and see if the output commands make sense. If they look good, copypaste those to Psh prompt and try running them. Use copy and paste, don't type the commands. If you do type, you might correct an error without realizing it.

Comment: Show `$env:Path` on both machines. Windows have `C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe` utility and that error message: *Invalid Parameter - Files* — coming from it. Your `convert` command get resolved to it not to `convert.exe` from ImageMagick.

Comment: I noticed that my file names have spaces - normally wrapping the FullName in quotes is sufficient but perhaps not on the server machine. Could this be an issue and if so how do i force the path name?

Comment: @PetSerAl: $env:Path is listing ImageMagick, so could it still be resolving to the Windows utility?

Comment: @val Is ImageMagick come before `C:\Windows\System32` or after?

Comment: @PetSerAl: It's listed before. Could it be spaces in file name? pls see my previous comment.

Comment: @vonPryz: I updated my question to reflect the fact that I have a space in the source path. there is a space before "Files" and this is the issue. How do i force the space as part of the filename?

Comment: @val Spaces in parameters does not affect how command resolves. Try to replace `convert` to the full path to ImageMagick `convert.exe`. Try to `Get-Command convert` to see how PowerShell resolve `convert` command.

Comment: @PetSerAl: I solved it. Thanks for that clarification: I added $tool = 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16\magick.exe' at the top and "& $tool" before convert.